# Right alignment without adding extra elements

Tags: html, css

I have a footer like this:

```
<style>
address {background:tan;}
</style>
<footer><address><a href="contact-form-url">Contact form</a>Contact me via <a href="mailto:js@example.com">email</a></address></footer>
```

How can I put `Contact me via <a href="mailto:js@example.com">email</a>` on the right side of the `footer/address` without adding extra elements?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what exactly you're looking for. However, since it seems that you don't want to move the entire `<address>` to the right (which can be done by `float: right`), you could add `text-align: right;` declaration to the `<address>` element in order to align its content to the right side.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/vimitele/1/edit)**.

As per your comment:

> I just want to put Contact me via `<a href="mailto:js@example.com">email</a>` on the right, not the whole address content.

You could align the inline elements to the right side at first (the above approach) and then `float` the **first ** `<a>` element (which is the first child of its parent in this particular instance) to the left side as follows:

```css
address { text-align: right; } /* move the inline elements to the right side */
address:after {                /* clearfix hack */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

address > a:first-child {      /* float the first anchor tag to the left */
  float: left;
}
```

**[Updated Example](http://jsbin.com/vimitele/2/edit)**

Depending on your markup, you may need to use `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child`. But `:first-child` works on this particular instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as mentioned in my question I just want to put `Contact me via <a href="mailto:js@example.com">email</a>` on the right, not the whole `address` content.

Comment: @Hermes Please note that `Contact me via...email` statement is the whole `address`'s content in your provided code. If there are some other elements, you should update the question.

Comment: Isn't this part of `address`: `<a href="contact-form-url">Contact form</a>`?

Comment: @Hermes Ah.. I missed that because of two `Contact` words there. I'll update the answer